# Magento 2.0 - Setting Custom Amount For Shipping Per Programmatically Created Orders

Tags: magento2

Does any of you know if this is possible? I am not sure if this can be done on the Flat Rate or if I need to create a custom shipping method.
I need to set the flat rate amount as the orders are imported from another store which already did the initial computation of the shipping.  I only need to set the shipping amount once I save those imported orders into Magento.